# Server.UrlEncode is not working for " * " ASP.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, urlencode

**Why?**

```
Server.UrlEncode("2*")
```

return `2*`

while it should return `2%2A`

as tested on [this demo site](https://web.archive.org/web/20190415035312/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/demos/Server.UrlEncode.asp)

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) specifically allows `*` in the URL:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>      reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>      unencoded within a URL.

So, there is no need to encode it.

The page you link to is a classic asp page so uses `UrlEncode`, so quite an old implementation and not the .NET one.

Comment: if it is safe then when i browse it... works Fine localhost:2008/PinchofblissWeb/search/name=2 but it doesn't browse localhost:2008/PinchofblissWeb/search/name=2*

Comment: @SOF User - I have tried passing in `2*` as a regular parameter (`?name=2*`) without a problem. You are probably hitting something in a redirect engine.

Answer (score 0):

According to .NET, `*` is a 'safe' character and needs not to be encoded.

Whether this is actually correct or not, I do not know.

Comment: if it is safe then when i browse it...

works Fine
http://localhost:2008/PinchofblissWeb/search/name=2

but it doesn't browse
http://localhost:2008/PinchofblissWeb/search/name=2*